# PHP MongoClient - connectTimeoutMS - in micro or milli seconds?

Tags: php, mongodb

I can't find any clear definition whether `connectTimeoutMS` option is in micro or milliseconds? Any ideas?

cheers.

Comment: `m` stands for mili, `u` for micro

Comment: @dev-null-dweller yes, usually this is the case. I think the documentation should mention it anyway. maybe a feature request should being made?

Comment: Standards are created to avoid such repetitions and explanations...

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Please post a reference to that *standard* if you know some. Note that the function is called `connectTimeoutMS`. Are you sure that microsoft will agree with that standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in milliseconds. I found that out by looking into the source code of the php extension:

*[mcon/types.h](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/mcon/types.h) line 203*

> int   connectTimeoutMS; /* How many milliseconds to wait for when connecting to nodes */

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl, I have managed to get Mongo team to update PHP doc too, should be there shortly.